# When to use MainWindow and when to use MainWindowController in MonoMac

Tags: monodevelop, xib, monomac

I have just started developing on MonoMac and MonoDevelop 3.0, and I'm really confused on where I am supposed to be routing up my IBOutlets and actions.  In all of the samples, `MainWindowController` is used to wire everything up. However, I just could not get anything to work except using `MainWindow` instead.

Also, I'm a little thrown off because in several of the samples `MainWindowController` shows up as a sub-folder to the nib.  But when I new up a solution, it shows up as its own file.

Any help appreciated

Edit: I uploaded the project to GitHub: https://github.com/ucsbmrf/MonoMacTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the issue probably stems from the fact that most tutorials you find on the web still reference older versions of MonoDevelop, XCode and IB. The new workflow for setting up a test project can be found in [this post](http://tufnelltech.blogspot.ca/2012/01/hello-os-x-from-c-five-steps.html) which takes into account the changes which incorporated Interface Builder into XCode in v4.2+.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I gave up on MonoMac due to lack of learning resources.

Comment: I figured that might be the case after 4 months. Hopefully people will find the time to help the documentation improve over time.

Comment: It's a shame you've given up, but there are no real shortcuts here. MonoMac is just a bunch of bindings to the Cocoa APIs so it's definitely beneficial to read up on XCode 4 and the Cocoa API of which there are plenty of learning resources online. I wrote the above rough and ready tutorial after reading Aaron Hillegass' book on Cocoa programming which I thoroughly recommend. I also have a bunch of other blog posts on building MonoMac applications that I need to find the time to tidy up and publish.